# How to communicate between two completely different sites

Tags: javascript, cookies

On an intranet, sales reps use two apps, a dialer for making phone calls, and an order entry system.

They both work, but they are totally different systems and servers. The dialer (vici dial) is on a Linux server, the order entry system is a single page app running on asp.net on Windows.

What is needed is a way to pass an id from the dialer, over to the order entry system so that the order entry system knows the id of the lead that converted to a sales.

Have thought of: putting the ID in a cookie on the Sales Rep's machine, and from the Order Entry System, have a timer that continually looks for the presence of that cookie, and if so, starts up a new order with that data.

Is that possible?  Or is there some other way to do it?  Am willing to accept kludge/workarounds at this point.

Comment: You won't be able to share cookie or web storage data between two different domains for security reasons. Your best bet is going to be to create an intermediary that the two systems can pass data to/from.

Comment: take a couple of hours and port the crud app to php and put it on apache on the linux box

Comment: does the dialer open the order entry system? you could just append a query string

Comment: can u put the ID into a table (with uniqueidentifier columns etc ofc)  and have the order entry system periodically test the table using ajax to see if there is any new ID for it?

Comment: @aw04, no, the dialer does not open the order entry system.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar, Using a table to communicate is not a bad idea.  Will give it some thought.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce - it's time to go wrestle that bear again.

Comment: so how does it open? it's not exactly clear how the communication should work, you say in your theoretical solution: "looks for cookie and if so, starts up a new order"... so does their browser just open to this web app out of nowhere?

Comment: greg, are both on the same intranet? if so you could make vicidial open the crud app with a query string.. if not, a database won't work either as one of the apps would have no ccess tooo it

Comment: If you can make changes to the systems, instead of adding a cookie, take the suggestion from @aw04 and initiate a request from the dialer to the order system passing the id in a query string.

Comment: @aw04 I agree that passing a query string to the OE app is the best idea.  If you want to post an answer, I will accept.

Comment: @GregGum posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the id as a query string in the url. Depending on when you want the app to open, you can open it directly or perhaps save/update a shortcut on a users desktop.

```
whatever.org?id=123
```

You can then retrieve the query string value on page load via javascript or asp.net and do as you wish.